# Matlab2tikz problem with contourf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

I´ve got a problem concerning inserting a Tikz-Plot from Matab into my Tex-file. The matlab-script I use to produce the plot is (Contourf-Plot):

```
%%
clear all; clc;
format bank;


fontname = 'Helvetica';
set(0,'defaultaxesfontname',fontname);
set(0,'defaulttextfontname',fontname);

fontsize = 18;
set(0,'defaultaxesfontsize',fontsize);
set(0,'defaulttextfontsize',fontsize);

%set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex')
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','tex')

%%
file = 'DOE_AUSWERTUNG_BP_DK.txt';

%%%Bestimmung der Spaltenanzahl
A=importdata(file);
Groesse=size(A);

Daten_KF=A(2:end,1:end-1);
X_Werte=A(1,1:end-1)';
Y_Werte=A(2:end,end);
%%
x=100;
y=100;
width=1120; %Format 16:9
height=630; %Format 16:9

%AGR
fig1=figure(1);
levels=0.5:0.1:1.5;
[C,h]=contourf(X_Werte,Y_Werte,Daten_KF,levels);box on; grid on; hold on;
clabel(C,h)
shading interp;
colormap(gray);hold on;

set(gca,'XLim',[(min(X_Werte)) (max(X_Werte))],'XTick',[0:10:100]);
set(gca,'YLim',[(min(Y_Werte)) (max(Y_Werte))],'YTick',-1:1:10);
set(gca,'ZLim',[0 1.5],'ZTick',0:0.1:2);
XLabel = xlabel('X [°]');
YLabel = ylabel('Y [°]');
colormap(gray);
colorbar;
l=legend('Zeit [s]');

set(l,'FontSize',14,'Location','NorthEast');
name = ([file 'Zeit']);
hold off;
%Speichern_des_Plots
tightInset = get(gca, 'TightInset');
position(1) = tightInset(1);
position(2) = tightInset(2);
position(3) = 1 - tightInset(1) - tightInset(3);
position(4) = 1 - tightInset(2) - tightInset(4);
set(gca, 'Position', position);
set(gcf,'PaperOrientation','landscape');
set(gcf,'PaperPosition', [1 1 28 19]);
print(gcf, '-dpdf', '-r1200',[name '.pdf']);
print(gcf,'-deps2', [name '.eps']);
print(gcf,'-dmeta', '-r1200', [name '.emf']); 
matlab2tikz([name '.tikz'],'standalone',true,'width','\figW','height','\figH','extraaxisoptions',['legend style={legend cell align=left,legend pos=north east,font=\footnotesize}']);
```

The resulting plot, I get in Matlab is:

[image]

When I use \input in latex to insert the tikzpicture, my latex-result is:

[image]

there is no problem at all, when I use *contour* instead of *contourf* in matlab or *surf* instead of *contourf*. But anyway, what I need is a filled contour plot with isoloines. Can anybody help me?

This is my Input for the matlab-Skript:

```
    1   5.67368 10.3474 15.0211 19.6947 24.3684 29.0421 33.7158 38.3895 43.0632 47.7368 52.4105 57.0842 61.7579 66.4316 71.1053 75.7789 80.4526 85.1263 89.8    90
1.12    0.8 0.72    0.72    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    1.00E-04
1.28    0.88    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.64    0.571521
1.2 0.88    0.8 0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    1.14294
1.12    0.88    0.8 0.8 0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 1.71436
1.04    0.96    0.88    0.8 0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    2.28579
1.04    0.96    0.96    0.96    1.04    1.12    1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 2.85721
0.96    1.04    0.96    1.04    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    1.12    3.42863
0.88    1.04    0.96    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    4.00005
0.88    1.04    0.96    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    1.04    4.57147
0.8 1.04    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    5.14289
0.8 1.04    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    5.71431
0.72    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    6.28574
0.72    0.88    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.96    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    6.85716
0.72    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    7.42858
0.64    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.88    8
```

And this is the resultig tikz-file:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.09524,0.09524,0.09524}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.28571,0.28571,0.28571}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.46032,0.46032,0.46032}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.65079,0.65079,0.65079}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figW,
height=0.919\figH,
at={(0\figW,0\figH)},
scale only axis,
point meta min=0.64,
point meta max=1.2,
xmin=1,
xmax=89.8,
xtick={  0,  10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100},
xlabel={X [°]},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0.0001,
ymax=8,
ytick={-1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10},
ylabel={Y [°]},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black},
legend style={legend cell align=left,legend pos=north east,font=\footnotesize},
colormap/blackwhite,
colorbar
]
\addplot[fill=black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
1   0.0001\\
1   8\\
89.8    8\\
89.8    0.0001\\
};
\addplot[fill=mycolor1,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
16.1895 0.0001\\
19.6947 0.42866575\\
20.863125   0.571521\\
24.3684 1.00008525\\
29.0421 1.00008525\\
33.7158 1.00008525\\
38.3895 1.00008525\\
43.0632 1.00008525\\
47.7368 1.00008525\\
52.4105 1.00008525\\
57.0842 1.00008525\\
61.7579 1.00008525\\
66.4316 1.00008525\\
71.1053 1.00008525\\
75.7789 1.00008525\\
80.4526 1.00008525\\
85.1263 1.00008525\\
89.8    1.00008525\\
};
\addplot[fill=mycolor1,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
2.16842 8\\
1   7.571435\\
};
\addplot[fill=mycolor2,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
5.67368 0.0001\\
8.01054 0.571521\\
10.3474 1.14294\\
10.3474 1.14294\\
15.0211 1.71436\\
15.0211 1.71436\\
19.6947 2.000075\\
24.3684 2.000075\\
29.0421 2.000075\\
33.7158 2.000075\\
38.3895 2.000075\\
43.0632 2.000075\\
47.7368 2.000075\\
52.4105 1.90483666666667\\
57.0842 1.90483666666667\\
61.7579 1.71436\\
61.7579 1.71436\\
66.4316 1.71436\\
71.1053 1.71436\\
75.7789 1.71436\\
80.4526 1.71436\\
85.1263 1.71436\\
89.8    1.71436\\
};
\addplot[fill=mycolor2,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
4.11578666666667    8\\
3.33684 7.42858\\
3.33684 6.85716\\
2.55789333333334    6.28574\\
1   5.71431\\
};
\addplot[fill=mycolor3,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
4.213155    0.0001\\
5.439996    0.571521\\
5.381575    1.14294\\
5.28420666666667    1.71436\\
5.67368 1.8572175\\
9.17897 2.28579\\
10.3474 2.428645\\
15.0211 2.6429275\\
19.6947 2.3572175\\
24.3684 2.33340833333333\\
29.0421 2.32150375\\
33.7158 2.32150375\\
38.3895 2.32150375\\
43.0632 2.32150375\\
47.7368 2.32150375\\
48.905225   2.28579\\
52.4105 2.1429325\\
57.0842 2.1429325\\
61.7579 2.07150375\\
66.4316 2.07150375\\
71.1053 2.07150375\\
75.7789 2.07150375\\
80.4526 2.07150375\\
85.1263 2.07150375\\
89.8    2.07150375\\
};
\addplot[fill=mycolor3,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
89.8    6.1428825\\
85.1263 6.1428825\\
80.4526 6.1428825\\
75.7789 6.1428825\\
71.1053 6.1428825\\
66.4316 6.1428825\\
61.7579 6.1428825\\
57.0842 6.1428825\\
52.4105 6.1428825\\
47.7368 6.1428825\\
43.0632 6.1428825\\
41.894775   6.28574\\
38.3895 6.714305\\
37.221075   6.85716\\
33.7158 7.285725\\
29.0421 7.285725\\
24.3684 7.285725\\
19.6947 7.285725\\
15.0211 7.285725\\
10.3474 7.285725\\
6.84211 6.85716\\
5.67368 6.714305\\
4.50526 6.28574\\
2.94736666666667    5.71431\\
2.94736666666667    5.14289\\
1.58421 4.57147\\
1.58421 4.00005\\
1   3.857195\\
};
\addplot[fill=mycolor4,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
2.75263 0.0001\\
4.271576    0.571521\\
3.92105 1.14294\\
3.33684 1.71436\\
3.33684 2.28579\\
3.33684 2.85721\\
5.67368 3.14292\\
8.01054 3.42863\\
8.01054 4.00005\\
8.01054 4.57147\\
8.01054 5.14289\\
8.01054 5.71431\\
5.67368 6.000025\\
4.89473333333333    5.71431\\
4.89473333333333    5.14289\\
4.50526 4.57147\\
4.50526 4.00005\\
3.33684 3.42863\\
1   3.14292\\
};
\addplot[fill=mycolor4,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
89.8    4.85718\\
85.1263 4.85718\\
80.4526 4.85718\\
75.7789 4.85718\\
71.1053 4.85718\\
66.4316 4.85718\\
61.7579 4.85718\\
57.0842 4.85718\\
52.4105 4.85718\\
47.7368 4.85718\\
43.0632 4.85718\\
38.3895 4.85718\\
33.7158 4.85718\\
29.0421 4.85718\\
24.3684 4.85718\\
19.6947 4.85718\\
15.0211 4.85718\\
12.68425    4.57147\\
12.68425    4.00005\\
12.68425    3.42863\\
15.0211 3.14292\\
17.3579 2.85721\\
19.6947 2.714355\\
24.3684 2.5715\\
29.0421 2.5000725\\
33.7158 2.5000725\\
38.3895 2.5000725\\
43.0632 2.5000725\\
47.7368 2.5000725\\
52.4105 2.38102666666667\\
57.0842 2.38102666666667\\
61.7579 2.38102666666667\\
66.4316 2.38102666666667\\
71.1053 2.38102666666667\\
75.7789 2.38102666666667\\
80.4526 2.38102666666667\\
85.1263 2.38102666666667\\
89.8    2.38102666666667\\
};
\addplot[fill=white!50!mycolor4,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
89.8    3.571485\\
85.1263 3.571485\\
80.4526 3.571485\\
75.7789 3.571485\\
71.1053 3.571485\\
66.4316 3.571485\\
61.7579 3.571485\\
57.0842 3.571485\\
52.4105 3.571485\\
47.7368 3.571485\\
43.0632 3.571485\\
38.3895 3.571485\\
33.7158 3.571485\\
29.0421 3.571485\\
24.3684 3.571485\\
19.6947 3.571485\\
18.5263 3.42863\\
19.6947 3.285775\\
23.199975   2.85721\\
24.3684 2.80959166666667\\
29.0421 2.67864125\\
33.7158 2.67864125\\
38.3895 2.67864125\\
43.0632 2.67864125\\
47.7368 2.67864125\\
52.4105 2.61911833333333\\
57.0842 2.61911833333333\\
61.7579 2.61911833333333\\
66.4316 2.61911833333333\\
71.1053 2.61911833333333\\
75.7789 2.61911833333333\\
80.4526 2.61911833333333\\
85.1263 2.61911833333333\\
89.8    2.61911833333333\\
};
\addplot[fill=white,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
29.0421 2.85721\\
29.0421 2.85721\\
33.7158 2.85721\\
38.3895 2.85721\\
43.0632 2.85721\\
47.7368 2.85721\\
52.4105 2.85721\\
57.0842 2.85721\\
61.7579 2.85721\\
66.4316 2.85721\\
71.1053 2.85721\\
75.7789 2.85721\\
80.4526 2.85721\\
85.1263 2.85721\\
89.8    2.85721\\
85.1263 2.85721\\
80.4526 2.85721\\
75.7789 2.85721\\
71.1053 2.85721\\
66.4316 2.85721\\
61.7579 2.85721\\
57.0842 2.85721\\
52.4105 2.85721\\
47.7368 2.85721\\
43.0632 2.85721\\
38.3895 2.85721\\
33.7158 2.85721\\
29.0421 2.85721\\
29.0421 2.85721\\
};
\addplot[fill=white!50!mycolor4,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
1.292105    0.0001\\
3.103156    0.571521\\
2.460525    1.14294\\
1.38947333333333    1.71436\\
1   1.8572175\\
};
\addplot[fill=white,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr] {%
%
x   y\\
1   0.2858105\\
1.934736    0.571521\\
1   1.14294\\
1   1.14294\\
};
\addlegendentry{Zeit [s]};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

thank you!!

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! I think you should pose this question in the user forum for `matlab2tikz` -- it seems its way to convert matlab's isolines to pgfplots fill instructions does not always work as expected. We could help you to fix the plot in question, but that does not touch the root cause.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your answer! Where can I find the `matlab2tikz` - user forum? Is it also a part of tex.sx?

Comment: I believe issues are reported at https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz

Comment: Thanks Christian again. I figured out that my problem is already an issue there that is unsolved ([https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues/723]). The problem ist that `matlab2tikz` can not generate `contourf`-plots that have unclosed iso-lines. I will try to handle these plots directly with pgf-plots though.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the underlying problem is a bug in `matlab2tikz`.

However, `pgfplots` 1.14 (release date august 2016) supports filled contour plots out of the box and without 3rd party tools. Your example needs can be visualized as follows:

1. take you `.m` file as-is, and run

.

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(X_Werte,Y_Werte);
data = [ X(:) Y(:) Z(:) ]
% or -ascii
save P.dat data -ASCII
size(X)
ans =
   15.00    20.00
```

2. use the resulting `P.dat` in `pgfplots` as follows:

.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},colorbar as legend,colormap/blackwhite,]
    \addplot3[
        contour filled={
           levels={0.5,0.6,...,1.5},
        },
        patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/cols=20,mesh/ordering=y varies,
    ]
    table {P.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The instruction `mesh/cols=20,mesh/ordering=y varies` tells `pgfplots` how to import the data file where `patch type=bilinear` improves the quality of the result.

[image]

Here, `colorbar as legend` configures the colorbar to describe all employed labels. Note that `contour filled` in `pgfplots` comes without label nodes inside of the image.