# How to set the isolines in a contour plot and observable with non-Acroread previewer

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add the isolines to the right plot generated by these lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15,
colormap={parula}{%
        rgb=(0.2081,0.1663,0.5292)rgb=(0.2116,0.1898,0.5777)rgb=(0.2123,0.2138,0.627)
        rgb=(0.2081,0.2386,0.6771)rgb=(0.1959,0.2645,0.7279)rgb=(0.1707,0.2919,0.7792)
        rgb=(0.1253,0.3242,0.8303)rgb=(0.0591,0.3598,0.8683)rgb=(0.0117,0.3875,0.882)
        rgb=(0.006,0.4086,0.8828) rgb=(0.0165,0.4266,0.8786)rgb=(0.0329,0.443,0.872)
        rgb=(0.0498,0.4586,0.8641)rgb=(0.0629,0.4737,0.8554)rgb=(0.0723,0.4887,0.8467)
        rgb=(0.0779,0.504,0.8384) rgb=(0.0793,0.52,0.8312)  rgb=(0.0749,0.5375,0.8263)
        rgb=(0.0641,0.557,0.824)  rgb=(0.0488,0.5772,0.8228)rgb=(0.0343,0.5966,0.8199)
        rgb=(0.0265,0.6137,0.8135)rgb=(0.0239,0.6287,0.8038)rgb=(0.0231,0.6418,0.7913)
        rgb=(0.0228,0.6535,0.7768)rgb=(0.0267,0.6642,0.7607)rgb=(0.0384,0.6743,0.7436)
        rgb=(0.059,0.6838,0.7254) rgb=(0.0843,0.6928,0.7062)rgb=(0.1133,0.7015,0.6859)
        rgb=(0.1453,0.7098,0.6646)rgb=(0.1801,0.7177,0.6424)rgb=(0.2178,0.725,0.6193)
        rgb=(0.2586,0.7317,0.5954)rgb=(0.3022,0.7376,0.5712)rgb=(0.3482,0.7424,0.5473)
        rgb=(0.3953,0.7459,0.5244)rgb=(0.442,0.7481,0.5033) rgb=(0.4871,0.7491,0.484)
        rgb=(0.53,0.7491,0.4661)  rgb=(0.5709,0.7485,0.4494)rgb=(0.6099,0.7473,0.4337)
        rgb=(0.6473,0.7456,0.4188)rgb=(0.6834,0.7435,0.4044)rgb=(0.7184,0.7411,0.3905)
        rgb=(0.7525,0.7384,0.3768)rgb=(0.7858,0.7356,0.3633)rgb=(0.8185,0.7327,0.3498)
        rgb=(0.8507,0.7299,0.336) rgb=(0.8824,0.7274,0.3217)rgb=(0.9139,0.7258,0.3063)
        rgb=(0.945,0.7261,0.2886) rgb=(0.9739,0.7314,0.2666)rgb=(0.9938,0.7455,0.2403)
        rgb=(0.999,0.7653,0.2164) rgb=(0.9955,0.7861,0.1967)rgb=(0.988,0.8066,0.1794)
        rgb=(0.9789,0.8271,0.1633)rgb=(0.9697,0.8481,0.1475)rgb=(0.9626,0.8705,0.1309)
        rgb=(0.9589,0.8949,0.1132)rgb=(0.9598,0.9218,0.0948)rgb=(0.9661,0.9514,0.0755)
        rgb=(0.9763,0.9831,0.0538)
        }
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{dfsa3c.dat}
0.12    0.5 0.
0.12    1.5 0.
0.12    2.5 0.
0.12    3.5 0.
0.12    4.5 0.
0.12    5.5 0.
0.12    6.5 0.
0.12    7.5 0.
0.12    8.5 0.
0.12    9.5 0.
0.12    10.5    0.
0.12    11.5    0.
0.12    12.5    0.
0.12    13.5    0.
0.12    14.5    0.
0.12    15.5    0.
0.12    16.5    0.
0.12    17.5    0.
0.12    18.5    0.

0.16    0.5 0.
0.16    1.5 0.
0.16    2.5 0.
0.16    3.5 0.
0.16    4.5 0.
0.16    5.5 0.
0.16    6.5 0.
0.16    7.5 0.
0.16    8.5 0.
0.16    9.5 0.
0.16    10.5    0.
0.16    11.5    0.
0.16    12.5    0.
0.16    13.5    0.
0.16    14.5    0.
0.16    15.5    0.
0.16    16.5    0.
0.16    17.5    0.
0.16    18.5    0.

0.2 0.5 0.
0.2 1.5 0.
0.2 2.5 0.
0.2 3.5 0.
0.2 4.5 0.
0.2 5.5 0.
0.2 6.5 0.
0.2 7.5 0.
0.2 8.5 0.
0.2 9.5 0.
0.2 10.5    0.
0.2 11.5    0.
0.2 12.5    0.
0.2 13.5    0.
0.2 14.5    0.
0.2 15.5    0.
0.2 16.5    0.
0.2 17.5    0.
0.2 18.5    0.

0.24    0.5 0.
0.24    1.5 0.
0.24    2.5 0.
0.24    3.5 0.
0.24    4.5 0.
0.24    5.5 0.
0.24    6.5 0.
0.24    7.5 0.
0.24    8.5 0.
0.24    9.5 0.012333333333333333
0.24    10.5    0.101
0.24    11.5    0.2747278202455409
0.24    12.5    0.46103719793646486
0.24    13.5    0.5046684223126646
0.24    14.5    0.483661499790532
0.24    15.5    0.5092097445038621
0.24    16.5    0.5
0.24    17.5    0.5021666666666667
0.24    18.5    0.506

0.28    0.5 0.
0.28    1.5 0.
0.28    2.5 0.
0.28    3.5 0.
0.28    4.5 0.
0.28    5.5 0.
0.28    6.5 0.0006666666666666666
0.28    7.5 0.035
0.28    8.5 0.4125
0.28    9.5 0.9543333333333334
0.28    10.5    1.
0.28    11.5    1.
0.28    12.5    1.
0.28    13.5    1.
0.28    14.5    1.
0.28    15.5    1.
0.28    16.5    1.
0.28    17.5    1.
0.28    18.5    1.

0.32    0.5 0.
0.32    1.5 0.
0.32    2.5 0.
0.32    3.5 0.
0.32    4.5 0.
0.32    5.5 0.00525
0.32    6.5 0.4053333333333333
0.32    7.5 0.907
0.32    8.5 0.996
0.32    9.5 1.
0.32    10.5    1.
0.32    11.5    1.
0.32    12.5    1.
0.32    13.5    1.
0.32    14.5    1.
0.32    15.5    1.
0.32    16.5    1.
0.32    17.5    1.
0.32    18.5    1.

0.36    0.5 0.
0.36    1.5 0.
0.36    2.5 0.
0.36    3.5 0.
0.36    4.5 0.
0.36    5.5 0.1665
0.36    6.5 0.9516666666666667
0.36    7.5 1.
0.36    8.5 1.
0.36    9.5 1.
0.36    10.5    1.
0.36    11.5    1.
0.36    12.5    1.
0.36    13.5    1.
0.36    14.5    1.
0.36    15.5    1.
0.36    16.5    1.
0.36    17.5    1.
0.36    18.5    1.

0.4 0.5 0.
0.4 1.5 0.
0.4 2.5 0.
0.4 3.5 0.0007524454477050414
0.4 4.5 0.07252856433184302
0.4 5.5 0.71425
0.4 6.5 0.9996666666666667
0.4 7.5 1.
0.4 8.5 1.
0.4 9.5 1.
0.4 10.5    1.
0.4 11.5    1.
0.4 12.5    1.
0.4 13.5    1.
0.4 14.5    1.
0.4 15.5    1.
0.4 16.5    1.
0.4 17.5    1.
0.4 18.5    1.

0.44    0.5 0.
0.44    1.5 0.
0.44    2.5 0.
0.44    3.5 0.013
0.44    4.5 0.489
0.44    5.5 0.988
0.44    6.5 1.
0.44    7.5 1.
0.44    8.5 1.
0.44    9.5 1.
0.44    10.5    1.
0.44    11.5    1.
0.44    12.5    1.
0.44    13.5    1.
0.44    14.5    1.
0.44    15.5    1.
0.44    16.5    1.
0.44    17.5    1.
0.44    18.5    1.

0.48    0.5 0.
0.48    1.5 0.
0.48    2.5 0.
0.48    3.5 0.1725
0.48    4.5 0.9245
0.48    5.5 0.99925
0.48    6.5 1.
0.48    7.5 1.
0.48    8.5 1.
0.48    9.5 1.
0.48    10.5    1.
0.48    11.5    1.
0.48    12.5    1.
0.48    13.5    1.
0.48    14.5    1.
0.48    15.5    1.
0.48    16.5    1.
0.48    17.5    1.
0.48    18.5    1.

0.52    0.5 0.
0.52    1.5 0.
0.52    2.5 0.001
0.52    3.5 0.522
0.52    4.5 1.
0.52    5.5 1.
0.52    6.5 1.
0.52    7.5 1.
0.52    8.5 1.
0.52    9.5 1.
0.52    10.5    1.
0.52    11.5    1.
0.52    12.5    1.
0.52    13.5    1.
0.52    14.5    1.
0.52    15.5    1.
0.52    16.5    1.
0.52    17.5    1.
0.52    18.5    1.

0.56    0.5 0.
0.56    1.5 0.
0.56    2.5 0.0045
0.56    3.5 0.758137205808713
0.56    4.5 0.9990029910269193
0.56    5.5 1.
0.56    6.5 1.
0.56    7.5 1.
0.56    8.5 1.
0.56    9.5 1.
0.56    10.5    1.
0.56    11.5    1.
0.56    12.5    1.
0.56    13.5    1.
0.56    14.5    1.
0.56    15.5    1.
0.56    16.5    1.
0.56    17.5    1.
0.56    18.5    1.

0.6 0.5 0.
0.6 1.5 0.
0.6 2.5 0.055
0.6 3.5 0.927122464312547
0.6 4.5 1.
0.6 5.5 1.
0.6 6.5 1.
0.6 7.5 1.
0.6 8.5 1.
0.6 9.5 1.
0.6 10.5    1.
0.6 11.5    1.
0.6 12.5    1.
0.6 13.5    1.
0.6 14.5    1.
0.6 15.5    1.
0.6 16.5    1.
0.6 17.5    1.
0.6 18.5    1.

0.64    0.5 0.
0.64    1.5 0.
0.64    2.5 0.2115
0.64    3.5 0.9932364729458918
0.64    4.5 1.
0.64    5.5 1.
0.64    6.5 1.
0.64    7.5 1.
0.64    8.5 1.
0.64    9.5 1.
0.64    10.5    1.
0.64    11.5    1.
0.64    12.5    1.
0.64    13.5    1.
0.64    14.5    1.
0.64    15.5    1.
0.64    16.5    1.
0.64    17.5    1.
0.64    18.5    1.

0.68    0.5 0.
0.68    1.5 0.
0.68    2.5 0.384
0.68    3.5 0.999498997995992
0.68    4.5 1.
0.68    5.5 1.
0.68    6.5 1.
0.68    7.5 1.
0.68    8.5 1.
0.68    9.5 1.
0.68    10.5    1.
0.68    11.5    1.
0.68    12.5    1.
0.68    13.5    1.
0.68    14.5    1.
0.68    15.5    1.
0.68    16.5    1.
0.68    17.5    1.
0.68    18.5    1.

0.72    0.5 0.
0.72    1.5 0.
0.72    2.5 0.5045
0.72    3.5 1.
0.72    4.5 1.
0.72    5.5 1.
0.72    6.5 1.
0.72    7.5 1.
0.72    8.5 1.
0.72    9.5 1.
0.72    10.5    1.
0.72    11.5    1.
0.72    12.5    1.
0.72    13.5    1.
0.72    14.5    1.
0.72    15.5    1.
0.72    16.5    1.
0.72    17.5    1.
0.72    18.5    1.

0.76    0.5 0.
0.76    1.5 0.0005
0.76    2.5 0.6215
0.76    3.5 1.
0.76    4.5 1.
0.76    5.5 1.
0.76    6.5 1.
0.76    7.5 1.
0.76    8.5 1.
0.76    9.5 1.
0.76    10.5    1.
0.76    11.5    1.
0.76    12.5    1.
0.76    13.5    1.
0.76    14.5    1.
0.76    15.5    1.
0.76    16.5    1.
0.76    17.5    1.
0.76    18.5    1.

0.8 0.5 0.
0.8 1.5 0.00175
0.8 2.5 0.7495
0.8 3.5 1.
0.8 4.5 1.
0.8 5.5 1.
0.8 6.5 1.
0.8 7.5 1.
0.8 8.5 1.
0.8 9.5 1.
0.8 10.5    1.
0.8 11.5    1.
0.8 12.5    1.
0.8 13.5    1.
0.8 14.5    1.
0.8 15.5    1.
0.8 16.5    1.
0.8 17.5    1.
0.8 18.5    1.

0.84    0.5 0.
0.84    1.5 0.004
0.84    2.5 0.873
0.84    3.5 1.
0.84    4.5 1.
0.84    5.5 1.
0.84    6.5 1.
0.84    7.5 1.
0.84    8.5 1.
0.84    9.5 1.
0.84    10.5    1.
0.84    11.5    1.
0.84    12.5    1.
0.84    13.5    1.
0.84    14.5    1.
0.84    15.5    1.
0.84    16.5    1.
0.84    17.5    1.
0.84    18.5    1.

0.88    0.5 0.
0.88    1.5 0.01825
0.88    2.5 0.94325
0.88    3.5 1.
0.88    4.5 1.
0.88    5.5 1.
0.88    6.5 1.
0.88    7.5 1.
0.88    8.5 1.
0.88    9.5 1.
0.88    10.5    1.
0.88    11.5    1.
0.88    12.5    1.
0.88    13.5    1.
0.88    14.5    1.
0.88    15.5    1.
0.88    16.5    1.
0.88    17.5    1.
0.88    18.5    1.

0.92    0.5 0.
0.92    1.5 0.07
0.92    2.5 0.988
0.92    3.5 1.
0.92    4.5 1.
0.92    5.5 1.
0.92    6.5 1.
0.92    7.5 1.
0.92    8.5 1.
0.92    9.5 1.
0.92    10.5    1.
0.92    11.5    1.
0.92    12.5    1.
0.92    13.5    1.
0.92    14.5    1.
0.92    15.5    1.
0.92    16.5    1.
0.92    17.5    1.
0.92    18.5    1.
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
% zlabel={$f(x,y) = x\cdot y$},
title=isolines,
small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=20,
]

           \addplot3 [ patch type=bilinear,
           point meta=z, 
           point meta max = 1,
           point meta min =0,
           contour gnuplot={labels=false, 
           % levels = {0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1}
           levels = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,  0.4, 0.5,  0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}
           }]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};
\end{axis}


    \begin{axis}[
        xshift=8cm,
        small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
        title = requires Acroread,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        % colormap/jet,
]

           \addplot3 [
           patch type=bilinear,
           %point meta= {tan(3*(z-1/2)*180/pi)},
           point meta max = 1,
           point meta min = 0,
           contour filled={labels=false, 
           % levels = {0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1}
           levels = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,  0.4, 0.5,  0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}
           }]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};
\end{axis}
    %%%%%
     % \begin{axis}[xshift=8cm,
%           xlabel=$x$,
%           ylabel=$y$,
%          title=DFSA,
%           small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
%            ]
%            \addplot3 [surf,
%            shader=interp, contour gnuplot ={filled,labels=false}]
%             table {dfsa3c.dat};
%         \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Besides, it is not possible to see the content of the figure on the right with a free previewer. I have to open the file with Acroread.
This problem is a limitation presented in the pgfplots manual pg.162.
Is there any way to overcome this limitation and to create the right-side contour plot with the isolines and observable with a non-Acrobat previewer?. Also, can the right figure have a *colorbar* like the left figure with smooth color transitions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This produces something that, when viewed with preview (the only pdf reader I have apart from acroread) something that might fit your description. It works as follows: we loop over the levels and

1. produce a standard contour plot. This is only a trick to let pgfplots write the coordinates of the contour in a file.
2. The data is recycled via `contour prepared` where we read the data. This then allows us to fill single areas.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15,
colormap={parula}{%
        rgb=(0.2081,0.1663,0.5292)rgb=(0.2116,0.1898,0.5777)rgb=(0.2123,0.2138,0.627)
        rgb=(0.2081,0.2386,0.6771)rgb=(0.1959,0.2645,0.7279)rgb=(0.1707,0.2919,0.7792)
        rgb=(0.1253,0.3242,0.8303)rgb=(0.0591,0.3598,0.8683)rgb=(0.0117,0.3875,0.882)
        rgb=(0.006,0.4086,0.8828) rgb=(0.0165,0.4266,0.8786)rgb=(0.0329,0.443,0.872)
        rgb=(0.0498,0.4586,0.8641)rgb=(0.0629,0.4737,0.8554)rgb=(0.0723,0.4887,0.8467)
        rgb=(0.0779,0.504,0.8384) rgb=(0.0793,0.52,0.8312)  rgb=(0.0749,0.5375,0.8263)
        rgb=(0.0641,0.557,0.824)  rgb=(0.0488,0.5772,0.8228)rgb=(0.0343,0.5966,0.8199)
        rgb=(0.0265,0.6137,0.8135)rgb=(0.0239,0.6287,0.8038)rgb=(0.0231,0.6418,0.7913)
        rgb=(0.0228,0.6535,0.7768)rgb=(0.0267,0.6642,0.7607)rgb=(0.0384,0.6743,0.7436)
        rgb=(0.059,0.6838,0.7254) rgb=(0.0843,0.6928,0.7062)rgb=(0.1133,0.7015,0.6859)
        rgb=(0.1453,0.7098,0.6646)rgb=(0.1801,0.7177,0.6424)rgb=(0.2178,0.725,0.6193)
        rgb=(0.2586,0.7317,0.5954)rgb=(0.3022,0.7376,0.5712)rgb=(0.3482,0.7424,0.5473)
        rgb=(0.3953,0.7459,0.5244)rgb=(0.442,0.7481,0.5033) rgb=(0.4871,0.7491,0.484)
        rgb=(0.53,0.7491,0.4661)  rgb=(0.5709,0.7485,0.4494)rgb=(0.6099,0.7473,0.4337)
        rgb=(0.6473,0.7456,0.4188)rgb=(0.6834,0.7435,0.4044)rgb=(0.7184,0.7411,0.3905)
        rgb=(0.7525,0.7384,0.3768)rgb=(0.7858,0.7356,0.3633)rgb=(0.8185,0.7327,0.3498)
        rgb=(0.8507,0.7299,0.336) rgb=(0.8824,0.7274,0.3217)rgb=(0.9139,0.7258,0.3063)
        rgb=(0.945,0.7261,0.2886) rgb=(0.9739,0.7314,0.2666)rgb=(0.9938,0.7455,0.2403)
        rgb=(0.999,0.7653,0.2164) rgb=(0.9955,0.7861,0.1967)rgb=(0.988,0.8066,0.1794)
        rgb=(0.9789,0.8271,0.1633)rgb=(0.9697,0.8481,0.1475)rgb=(0.9626,0.8705,0.1309)
        rgb=(0.9589,0.8949,0.1132)rgb=(0.9598,0.9218,0.0948)rgb=(0.9661,0.9514,0.0755)
        rgb=(0.9763,0.9831,0.0538)
        }
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{dfsa3c.dat}
0.12    0.5 0.
0.12    1.5 0.
0.12    2.5 0.
0.12    3.5 0.
0.12    4.5 0.
0.12    5.5 0.
0.12    6.5 0.
0.12    7.5 0.
0.12    8.5 0.
0.12    9.5 0.
0.12    10.5    0.
0.12    11.5    0.
0.12    12.5    0.
0.12    13.5    0.
0.12    14.5    0.
0.12    15.5    0.
0.12    16.5    0.
0.12    17.5    0.
0.12    18.5    0.

0.16    0.5 0.
0.16    1.5 0.
0.16    2.5 0.
0.16    3.5 0.
0.16    4.5 0.
0.16    5.5 0.
0.16    6.5 0.
0.16    7.5 0.
0.16    8.5 0.
0.16    9.5 0.
0.16    10.5    0.
0.16    11.5    0.
0.16    12.5    0.
0.16    13.5    0.
0.16    14.5    0.
0.16    15.5    0.
0.16    16.5    0.
0.16    17.5    0.
0.16    18.5    0.

0.2 0.5 0.
0.2 1.5 0.
0.2 2.5 0.
0.2 3.5 0.
0.2 4.5 0.
0.2 5.5 0.
0.2 6.5 0.
0.2 7.5 0.
0.2 8.5 0.
0.2 9.5 0.
0.2 10.5    0.
0.2 11.5    0.
0.2 12.5    0.
0.2 13.5    0.
0.2 14.5    0.
0.2 15.5    0.
0.2 16.5    0.
0.2 17.5    0.
0.2 18.5    0.

0.24    0.5 0.
0.24    1.5 0.
0.24    2.5 0.
0.24    3.5 0.
0.24    4.5 0.
0.24    5.5 0.
0.24    6.5 0.
0.24    7.5 0.
0.24    8.5 0.
0.24    9.5 0.012333333333333333
0.24    10.5    0.101
0.24    11.5    0.2747278202455409
0.24    12.5    0.46103719793646486
0.24    13.5    0.5046684223126646
0.24    14.5    0.483661499790532
0.24    15.5    0.5092097445038621
0.24    16.5    0.5
0.24    17.5    0.5021666666666667
0.24    18.5    0.506

0.28    0.5 0.
0.28    1.5 0.
0.28    2.5 0.
0.28    3.5 0.
0.28    4.5 0.
0.28    5.5 0.
0.28    6.5 0.0006666666666666666
0.28    7.5 0.035
0.28    8.5 0.4125
0.28    9.5 0.9543333333333334
0.28    10.5    1.
0.28    11.5    1.
0.28    12.5    1.
0.28    13.5    1.
0.28    14.5    1.
0.28    15.5    1.
0.28    16.5    1.
0.28    17.5    1.
0.28    18.5    1.

0.32    0.5 0.
0.32    1.5 0.
0.32    2.5 0.
0.32    3.5 0.
0.32    4.5 0.
0.32    5.5 0.00525
0.32    6.5 0.4053333333333333
0.32    7.5 0.907
0.32    8.5 0.996
0.32    9.5 1.
0.32    10.5    1.
0.32    11.5    1.
0.32    12.5    1.
0.32    13.5    1.
0.32    14.5    1.
0.32    15.5    1.
0.32    16.5    1.
0.32    17.5    1.
0.32    18.5    1.

0.36    0.5 0.
0.36    1.5 0.
0.36    2.5 0.
0.36    3.5 0.
0.36    4.5 0.
0.36    5.5 0.1665
0.36    6.5 0.9516666666666667
0.36    7.5 1.
0.36    8.5 1.
0.36    9.5 1.
0.36    10.5    1.
0.36    11.5    1.
0.36    12.5    1.
0.36    13.5    1.
0.36    14.5    1.
0.36    15.5    1.
0.36    16.5    1.
0.36    17.5    1.
0.36    18.5    1.

0.4 0.5 0.
0.4 1.5 0.
0.4 2.5 0.
0.4 3.5 0.0007524454477050414
0.4 4.5 0.07252856433184302
0.4 5.5 0.71425
0.4 6.5 0.9996666666666667
0.4 7.5 1.
0.4 8.5 1.
0.4 9.5 1.
0.4 10.5    1.
0.4 11.5    1.
0.4 12.5    1.
0.4 13.5    1.
0.4 14.5    1.
0.4 15.5    1.
0.4 16.5    1.
0.4 17.5    1.
0.4 18.5    1.

0.44    0.5 0.
0.44    1.5 0.
0.44    2.5 0.
0.44    3.5 0.013
0.44    4.5 0.489
0.44    5.5 0.988
0.44    6.5 1.
0.44    7.5 1.
0.44    8.5 1.
0.44    9.5 1.
0.44    10.5    1.
0.44    11.5    1.
0.44    12.5    1.
0.44    13.5    1.
0.44    14.5    1.
0.44    15.5    1.
0.44    16.5    1.
0.44    17.5    1.
0.44    18.5    1.

0.48    0.5 0.
0.48    1.5 0.
0.48    2.5 0.
0.48    3.5 0.1725
0.48    4.5 0.9245
0.48    5.5 0.99925
0.48    6.5 1.
0.48    7.5 1.
0.48    8.5 1.
0.48    9.5 1.
0.48    10.5    1.
0.48    11.5    1.
0.48    12.5    1.
0.48    13.5    1.
0.48    14.5    1.
0.48    15.5    1.
0.48    16.5    1.
0.48    17.5    1.
0.48    18.5    1.

0.52    0.5 0.
0.52    1.5 0.
0.52    2.5 0.001
0.52    3.5 0.522
0.52    4.5 1.
0.52    5.5 1.
0.52    6.5 1.
0.52    7.5 1.
0.52    8.5 1.
0.52    9.5 1.
0.52    10.5    1.
0.52    11.5    1.
0.52    12.5    1.
0.52    13.5    1.
0.52    14.5    1.
0.52    15.5    1.
0.52    16.5    1.
0.52    17.5    1.
0.52    18.5    1.

0.56    0.5 0.
0.56    1.5 0.
0.56    2.5 0.0045
0.56    3.5 0.758137205808713
0.56    4.5 0.9990029910269193
0.56    5.5 1.
0.56    6.5 1.
0.56    7.5 1.
0.56    8.5 1.
0.56    9.5 1.
0.56    10.5    1.
0.56    11.5    1.
0.56    12.5    1.
0.56    13.5    1.
0.56    14.5    1.
0.56    15.5    1.
0.56    16.5    1.
0.56    17.5    1.
0.56    18.5    1.

0.6 0.5 0.
0.6 1.5 0.
0.6 2.5 0.055
0.6 3.5 0.927122464312547
0.6 4.5 1.
0.6 5.5 1.
0.6 6.5 1.
0.6 7.5 1.
0.6 8.5 1.
0.6 9.5 1.
0.6 10.5    1.
0.6 11.5    1.
0.6 12.5    1.
0.6 13.5    1.
0.6 14.5    1.
0.6 15.5    1.
0.6 16.5    1.
0.6 17.5    1.
0.6 18.5    1.

0.64    0.5 0.
0.64    1.5 0.
0.64    2.5 0.2115
0.64    3.5 0.9932364729458918
0.64    4.5 1.
0.64    5.5 1.
0.64    6.5 1.
0.64    7.5 1.
0.64    8.5 1.
0.64    9.5 1.
0.64    10.5    1.
0.64    11.5    1.
0.64    12.5    1.
0.64    13.5    1.
0.64    14.5    1.
0.64    15.5    1.
0.64    16.5    1.
0.64    17.5    1.
0.64    18.5    1.

0.68    0.5 0.
0.68    1.5 0.
0.68    2.5 0.384
0.68    3.5 0.999498997995992
0.68    4.5 1.
0.68    5.5 1.
0.68    6.5 1.
0.68    7.5 1.
0.68    8.5 1.
0.68    9.5 1.
0.68    10.5    1.
0.68    11.5    1.
0.68    12.5    1.
0.68    13.5    1.
0.68    14.5    1.
0.68    15.5    1.
0.68    16.5    1.
0.68    17.5    1.
0.68    18.5    1.

0.72    0.5 0.
0.72    1.5 0.
0.72    2.5 0.5045
0.72    3.5 1.
0.72    4.5 1.
0.72    5.5 1.
0.72    6.5 1.
0.72    7.5 1.
0.72    8.5 1.
0.72    9.5 1.
0.72    10.5    1.
0.72    11.5    1.
0.72    12.5    1.
0.72    13.5    1.
0.72    14.5    1.
0.72    15.5    1.
0.72    16.5    1.
0.72    17.5    1.
0.72    18.5    1.

0.76    0.5 0.
0.76    1.5 0.0005
0.76    2.5 0.6215
0.76    3.5 1.
0.76    4.5 1.
0.76    5.5 1.
0.76    6.5 1.
0.76    7.5 1.
0.76    8.5 1.
0.76    9.5 1.
0.76    10.5    1.
0.76    11.5    1.
0.76    12.5    1.
0.76    13.5    1.
0.76    14.5    1.
0.76    15.5    1.
0.76    16.5    1.
0.76    17.5    1.
0.76    18.5    1.

0.8 0.5 0.
0.8 1.5 0.00175
0.8 2.5 0.7495
0.8 3.5 1.
0.8 4.5 1.
0.8 5.5 1.
0.8 6.5 1.
0.8 7.5 1.
0.8 8.5 1.
0.8 9.5 1.
0.8 10.5    1.
0.8 11.5    1.
0.8 12.5    1.
0.8 13.5    1.
0.8 14.5    1.
0.8 15.5    1.
0.8 16.5    1.
0.8 17.5    1.
0.8 18.5    1.

0.84    0.5 0.
0.84    1.5 0.004
0.84    2.5 0.873
0.84    3.5 1.
0.84    4.5 1.
0.84    5.5 1.
0.84    6.5 1.
0.84    7.5 1.
0.84    8.5 1.
0.84    9.5 1.
0.84    10.5    1.
0.84    11.5    1.
0.84    12.5    1.
0.84    13.5    1.
0.84    14.5    1.
0.84    15.5    1.
0.84    16.5    1.
0.84    17.5    1.
0.84    18.5    1.

0.88    0.5 0.
0.88    1.5 0.01825
0.88    2.5 0.94325
0.88    3.5 1.
0.88    4.5 1.
0.88    5.5 1.
0.88    6.5 1.
0.88    7.5 1.
0.88    8.5 1.
0.88    9.5 1.
0.88    10.5    1.
0.88    11.5    1.
0.88    12.5    1.
0.88    13.5    1.
0.88    14.5    1.
0.88    15.5    1.
0.88    16.5    1.
0.88    17.5    1.
0.88    18.5    1.

0.92    0.5 0.
0.92    1.5 0.07
0.92    2.5 0.988
0.92    3.5 1.
0.92    4.5 1.
0.92    5.5 1.
0.92    6.5 1.
0.92    7.5 1.
0.92    8.5 1.
0.92    9.5 1.
0.92    10.5    1.
0.92    11.5    1.
0.92    12.5    1.
0.92    13.5    1.
0.92    14.5    1.
0.92    15.5    1.
0.92    16.5    1.
0.92    17.5    1.
0.92    18.5    1.
\end{filecontents*}
\newcounter{plotno}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \begin{axis}[set layers,
   xlabel=$x$,
   ylabel=$y$,
   title=several contours,
   small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
   xmin=0,
   xmax=1,
   ymin=0,
   ymax=20,
   ]
  \setcounter{plotno}{-1}
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,  0.4, 0.5,  0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}
    {\addplot3 [ patch type=bilinear,
           point meta=z, 
           point meta max = 1,
           point meta min =0,
           contour gnuplot={labels=false, 
           % levels = {0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1}
           levels = {#1}
           }]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};
     \stepcounter{plotno}
     \addplot[contour prepared={labels=false,filled},fill=mapped color] table
       {\jobname_contourtmp\number\value{plotno}.table} coordinate[pos=0](p\number\value{plotno}-start)
        coordinate[pos=1](p\number\value{plotno}-end)  
        [insert path={(p\number\value{plotno}-end)-|(p\number\value{plotno}-start)}];
    }
    \pgfplotsonlayer{axis background}
     \pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{0}
     \fill[mapped color] (0.1,1) rectangle 
     (p\number\value{plotno}-end -| p\number\value{plotno}-start);
    \endpgfplotsonlayer
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result on preview (the result on acroread looks identical):

[image]

If we change the axis code to become similar to your second plot,

```
 \begin{axis}[set layers,
   xlabel=$x$,
   ylabel=$y$,
   xmin=0.1,
   title=several contours,
   small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
   ]
  \setcounter{plotno}{-1}
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,  0.4, 0.5,  0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}
    {\addplot3 [ patch type=bilinear,
           point meta=z, 
           point meta max = 1,
           point meta min =0,
           contour gnuplot={labels=false, 
           % levels = {0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1}
           levels = {#1}
           }]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};
     \stepcounter{plotno}
     \addplot[contour prepared={labels=false,filled},fill=mapped color] table
       {\jobname_contourtmp\number\value{plotno}.table} coordinate[pos=0](p\number\value{plotno}-start)
        coordinate[pos=1](p\number\value{plotno}-end)  
        [insert path={(p\number\value{plotno}-end)-|(p\number\value{plotno}-start)}];
    }
    \pgfplotsonlayer{axis background}
     \pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{0}
     \fill[mapped color] (current axis.south west) rectangle 
     (current axis.north east);
    \endpgfplotsonlayer
\end{axis}
```

we obtain a similar picture

[image]

Some things here, such as the way the paths get filled to shade the area, are specific to your situation, others not. What is meant by this is that

```
 [insert path={(p\number\value{plotno}-end)-|(p\number\value{plotno}-start)}]
```

is specific to your situation. If the contours close, you won't need it and in other situations you may need e.g. `|-` instead of `-|`. On the other hand, the above trick allows you to recycle any contour that you have produced with gnuplot.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have noticed that the dark blue zones in contact with the rest of the plot are not aligned and also the plot does not fulfill the frame. Is there a way to do it?. The comment  *...shade the area, are specific to your situation, others not* would mean that with other data file the solution will not work? Thank you.

Comment: I have also found this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349849/pgfplots-how-to-imitate-matlab-filled-contour-plot, but I do not know if it can be used with my plot.

Comment: @user1993416 I tried to address the questions in the edit. It is quite conceivable that the linked answer you found (also) allows you to solve your problem. I couldn't make it work here, though, but probably I was doing something stupid.